# How do I achieve this custom Soap request using PHP's Soap class?

Tags: php, soap

I need to create a Soap request using PHP's Soap extension. **I have searched and read both SO questions and the PHP.net manual**, however, I have not been able to find a plain English explanation regarding how to implement a custom header with multiple namespaces, a special type, etc. Basically, I just find all the current documentation very difficult to understand, and need someone to offer a more down-to-earth explanation of how to accomplish the request below:

```
<OAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.some-url1.com" xmlns:ns2="http://www.some-url2.com" xmlns:ns3="http://www.some-url3.com">
<OAP-ENV:Header>
<s2:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
<s2:UsernameToken>
<s2:Username>someusername</ns2:Username>
<s2:Password Type="http://www.some-url4.com">somepassword</ns2:Password></ns2:UsernameToken></ns2:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header>
<OAP-ENV:Body>
<s1:invokeSomeService>
<s3:someRequest ns3:someReferenceNumber="912" ns3:locale="en_US" ns3:someAliasName="SOME_NAME" ns3:someTrackingID="THE-ID-123">
<s3:inputCriteria>
<s3:name>
<s3:firstName>John</ns3:firstName>
<s3:lastName>BBITTERSWEET</ns3:lastName></ns3:name>
<s3:address ns3:someExtraInfo="EXTRA_INFO_HERE">
<s3:addressLine1>1 Main St</ns3:addressLine1>
<s3:city>Anywhere</ns3:city>
<s3:stateCode>NY</ns3:stateCode>
<s3:postalCode>12345</ns3:postalCode>
<s3:countryCode>US</ns3:countryCode></ns3:address></ns3:inputCriteria></ns3:someRequest></ns1:invokeSomeService></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: "Basically, I just find all the current documentation very difficult to understand" -- Oh, it's not the documentation that's the problem.  Despite the [S in SOAP originally standing for "Simple"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), SOAP is anything but.  You may need to dig into the XML with [one of the XML extensions](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) and put together the SOAP packet yourself.  I'd suggest following up with the people supplying the SOAP service and asking them if they have anything more simple and sane, like JSON + REST.

Comment: Unfortunately, all they offer is a Soap API and do not even provide PHP examples.

Would it be possible to just manually include all of the XML and use that as the request (rather than using the Soap/XML functions to build it)? If so, how?